# Logic Behind Type-Casting [Explicitly] in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, casting

Basically Explicit type casting means there is Possible loss of precision

example :

```
short s = 256;
byte b = (byte) s;
Console.WriteLine(b);
// output : 0
```

or

```
short s = 257;
byte b = (byte) s;
Console.WriteLine(b);
// output : 1
```

or

```
short s = 1024;
byte b = (byte)s;
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.ReadKey();
// output : 0
```

Base behind this output ... ?

Comment: What did you *expect* the code to do and why? You can't just post the code examples and expect us to deduce your expectations.

Comment: What outputs did you expect

Comment: Can you be more specific on what your confusion is?  It's pretty basic binary math so I 'm not sure exactly what you're confused on other than that.

Comment: It's literally truncating bits.  So try writing those values in binary and it should be more obvious what's happening.

Comment: Are you asking *why* you would ever want to truncate data in that way?

Comment: because you cant store 16 bits into 8 bits. so first 8 bits can be stored but the next 8 bits will gone.

Comment: This issue isn't about casting, it's a simple overflow.


In datatype byte you can store values between `0` and `255`. if you try to store `257` then you get an overflow at `255` and it starts at `0` again.

Comment: I want to know the base behind this code...?

Comment: Maybe you should look into the [byte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx) documentation - more specifically the *range*.

Comment: `short` is consist of two bytes. but `byte` is just one byte. now 256 is `00000001 00000000` in binary. the first byte can be saved inside `byte`. as you see all bits are 0 so you get 0. but 257 is `00000001 00000001`. so you get 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short is a 2-byte number, byte is 1-byte!

When you cast from two bytes to one you are losing the first

8 bits: 1024 (short: "0000 0100" "0000 0000").

Which in binary becomes (binary: "0000 0000") = 0.

The base behind your output is simple:

1. Every number is represented as bits, every 8 bits create 1 byte.
2. Byte holds numbers from "0" to "255".
3. If you convert bigger number to smaller in programing you are losing bits not just precision.
4. In your case you are losing every bit after the 8 (If the number you are trying to convert has value holed in its last 8 bits (bit can be 1 or 0) you will get it if not you will get 0).

P.S. Use windows calculator in programmer mode or find a program in google to convert number to bits and it will become more clear to you.